# .attr() as a variable in attribute selector not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have code like this

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input id="post-titie" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui olive message" for-field="post-title" hidden>
    <div class="header">About Title</div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Visitors can see your title even if they're not logged in.</li>
        <li>The title is public.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$('.form textarea, :input').focus(function(){

    var forwhom = $(this).attr('id'); /* not working */
    /* var forwhom = 'post-title';  works */

    var _msg = $(this).parents().eq(2).find('div[for-field="'+forwhom+'"]');
    $(_msg).transition('fade down').transition('show');

    console.log(forwhom);
    console.log(_msg);
}
```

What I want to do is when `<input>` or `<textarea>` focused, show messages div with `.message` class.

I make `$(this).attr('id')` as a variable (eg. `post-title`), and find it with `.find('div[for-field="'+forwhom+'"]')`. This is not working.

But If I replace `var forwhom` from `$(this).attr('id')` (jQ selector) to a absolute value like `post-title`, It does work.

It's strange! According to jQuery documentation, the `.attr()` method returns a string not an object.

What is the problem?

Comment: simply try this `$(':input')` since :input is a jquery extension

Comment: It works fine when I try it: http://jsbin.com/pusoyej/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Div` attribute `for-field="post-title"` and `input` has `post-titie` there is `spelling mistake`.

`post-title` and `post-titie` are not same that's why your code is not finding the div with for attribute.

Comment: It's misspell. I was embarrassed.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting id attribute. Check for console error:

```
$(function(){
    $('.form textarea, :input').focus(function(){

    var forwhom = $(this).attr('id'); /*  working */
    /* var forwhom = 'post-title';  works */

    console.log(forwhom);
});

});
```

Here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/x1ju006b/1/

Answer (score 0):

some tips:

1) use chrome dev tools to test out your selectors in the console

2) use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

3) `.closest()` instead of `$(this).parents().eq(2)`